# WCF Services with Entity Framework locks SQLite database

Tags: database, wcf, sqlite, transactions, entity-framework-6

I have created a WCF service with multiple service methods which read and commit transactions to a SQLite database. It gives errors like below when multiple services reading Entities concurrently.

> An error was reported while committing a database transaction but it could not be determined whether the transaction succeeded or failed on the database server. See the inner exception and http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=313468 for more information.
>
> System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.CommitFailedException: An error was reported while committing a database transaction but it could not be determined whether the transaction succeeded or failed on the database server. See the inner exception and http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=313468 for more information. ---> System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException: database is locked
>   database is locked

I have tried with different configurations like for services

```
InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single

ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple
```

Please help me to solve the problem.